# match one to one value from list

Tags: python, regex

Below is the code i am running and getting respective `output`, please let me know how to get `expected output`. I am trying to match one to one value, but it is getting one to all.

```
data=["(array['AZ','XCA'] <@ type_list AND (array['jh-ee60','6E16'] <@ value_list OR array['jh-ee30','TO-IO'] <@ value_list)",
 "(array['Q','SSA'] <@ type_list AND array['3WE.5_%_WW21_','AQWW_662'] <@ value_list)",
 "(array['system','s_num'] <@ type_list AND (array['V378.63','KMSS'] <@ value_list OR array['D885.13','UASS'] <@ value_list OR array['DV5.1','R'] <@ value_list OR array['DV25.1','W'] <@ value_list)"]

import re
def rplceOR(d):

        r = re.compile(r"array\['(.*?)','(.*?)']")    
        for s in d:
            m = r.search(s)
            if m:                             
                array_vals = r.findall(s, s.index("<@ type_list"))
                if len(array_vals) > 0:
                    print ("(type_value LIKE ALL ({}))".format(" OR type_value LIKE ALL ".join(["'%{}={};%'".format(m.group(1), x) for x in array_vals])))

rplceOR(data)
```

output

```
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%AZ=('jh-ee60', '6E16');%' OR type_value LIKE ALL '%AZ=('jh-ee30', 'TO-IO');%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%Q=('3WE.5_%_WW21_', 'AQWW_662');%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=('V378.63', 'KMSS');%' OR type_value LIKE ALL '%system=('D885.13', 'UASS');%' OR type_value LIKE ALL '%system=('DV5.1', 'R');%' OR type_value LIKE ALL '%system=('DV25.1', 'W');%'))
```

expected output

```
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%AZ=jh-ee60;%','%XCA=6E16;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%AZ=jh-ee30;%','%XCA=TO-IO;%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%Q=3WE.5_%_WW21_;%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=V378.63;%','%s_num=KMSS;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=D885.13;%','%s_num=UASS;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=DV5.1;%','%s_num=R;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=DV25.1;%','%s_num=W;%'))
```

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/QWUzAc? Are you sure the second one should be `(type_value LIKE ALL ('%Q=3WE.5_%_WW21_;%'))` and not `(type_value LIKE ALL ('%Q=3WE.5_%_WW21_;%','%SSA=AQWW_662;%'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now have two groups inside the pattern you need to pass two values to the `format` method.

You may use

```
print("(type_value LIKE ALL ({}))".format(") OR type_value LIKE ALL (".join(["'%{0}={2};%','%{1}={3};%'".format(m.group(1), m.group(2), x, y) for x,y in array_vals])))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QWUzAc).

Output:

```
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%AZ=jh-ee60;%','%XCA=6E16;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%AZ=jh-ee30;%','%XCA=TO-IO;%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%Q=3WE.5_%_WW21_;%','%SSA=AQWW_662;%'))
(type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=V378.63;%','%s_num=KMSS;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=D885.13;%','%s_num=UASS;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=DV5.1;%','%s_num=R;%') OR type_value LIKE ALL ('%system=DV25.1;%','%s_num=W;%'))
```

Comment: Thanks again, i was wondering if you are available or not. Thanks again, I will try for three groups now.

Comment: Note that probably you should also use `r"array\['([^']*)','([^']*)']"` pattern in order not to overmatch.

Comment: Sure, will consider that. Thanks again.